# Non-categorical properties

Tags: category-theory

In topology, there are some properties that are not topological, i.e. that are not preserved by homeomorphisms. Think for instance of completeness or of the property of being a Cauchy sequence.

Now, in category theory, we can use the terminology *categorical properties* to indicate all those properties preserved by isomorphisms of categories (I'm not interested in equivalence but in isomorphisms). Think for instance of the repleteness of a subcategory, its reflectivity and so on. Now, my question is: are there some properties that are not categorical (in the above sense)?

Comment: Of course. For example: "$\varnothing$ is an object in this category".

Comment: Both examples you've given arise because they are defined in terms of extra structure (a metric) that isn't expected to be preserved under your notion of isomorphism (which preserves only the topology).  It's easy to produce examples of that kind.  For example, suppose that you consider categories and also distinguish one object in each category.  With no special requirements on which object is distinguished, being the distinguished object won't be preserved by isomorphism.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what I wrote, and also what Alex wrote, are not the kind of thing you had in mind.  I don't see an easy way to make the question more precise in a way that avoids these trivial examples though.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yeah, it's difficult to formalize what I've in mind. Let $F: \mathfrak{C} \to \mathfrak{D}$ be an isomorphism of concrete categories over the same base category and $\mathfrak{B}$ a full subcategory satisfying some tecnical properties on the faithful functors, on subobjects and epi-mono factorizations. Now, these properties are all preserved by isomorphisms, so the essential image of $\mathfrak{B}$ has the same properties. Generally, properties defined by suitable morphisms and functors well behave. Might something pathological (in a not obvious way) be defined through morphisms?

Comment: @TheWanderer You can look at groups and group homomorphisms first (after all, groups are one-object groupoids). What properties of a groups are not preserved by an isomorphism of groups. Arguably none that are relevant in any sense (for groups). To get some you need to add extra structure that was not intended.